# SQL Silent Install ignoring config.ini

Tags: sql-server, powershell, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to install SQL using a config.ini file but it doesn't seem to accept the parameters set in the file.

For example, at the top of my file I have:

```
;SQL Server 2017 Configuration File
[OPTIONS]

IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS="True"
```

I run this:

`C:\Temp\sql-server-2017.exe /ConfigurationFile="C:\Temp\sql-config.ini"`

And yet, it will open the install window and ask me to "Accept Terms"

Another example, I have quiet simple set to true:

```
; Setup will not display any user interface. 

QUIET="False"

; Setup will display progress only, without any user interaction. 

QUIETSIMPLE="True"
```

But when I run: `C:\Temp\sql-server-2017.exe /ConfigurationFile=C:\Temp\sql-config.ini /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /MediaPath=C:\Temp\SQL`

I get this in the summary and error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried putting the /Q or /QS in the command line?

Comment: `c:\temp\sql-server-2017.exe /ConfigurationFile="C:\temp\sql-config.ini" /MediaPath="C:\Temp\SQL" /iacceptsqlserverlicenseterms /indicateprogress=false /q` this is what ended up working for me but I don't understand why it's not getting these values from the `config.ini` file

Comment: Its probably so it can pass it to the program that executes the sql-server-2017.exe, which then loads in the configuration file